# How to prevent middle column of HTML table from getting squeezed when screen resizes?

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I have an HTML table three columns by four rows, and in the CSS I specify each cell's height and width in pixels. When the screen is large or small the cells appear the correct size, but somewhere in between large and small the width of the middle column gets squeezed and is much narrower than it should be. How can I keep the width constant?

- I'm using Zurb Foundation for layout.
- I tried it in the most recent Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.102) and
  Firefox (26.0).
- The problem occurs when the screen width is between approximately 640
  and 800 pixels wide. Above that and below that is fine.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns left">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Header description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='key'>1</td>
        <td class='key'>2</td>
        <td class='key'>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='key'>4</td>
        <td class='key'>5</td>
        <td class='key'>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='key'>7</td>
        <td class='key'>8</td>
        <td class='key'>9</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns left">
    Other Content...
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the relevant CSS for the class 'key':

```
.key {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 53px;
  width: 53px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: try using media tag. This link would help http://jsfiddle.net/Q2ME9/

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine. Which browser are you using? Try set the min-width property and if you are using responsive design make sure it is not overwriting the width property.

Comment: I tried it in the most recent Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.102) and Firefox (26.0). Adding min-width to the css does not seem to help. The problem occurs when the screen width is between approximately 640 and 800 pixels wide.

Comment: @koanima is your <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns left"> or <div class="row"> restricting the width?

Comment: The <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns left"> restricts the width. With the Foundation Zurb grid, each <div class='row'> is divided into twelve columns.

Comment: try adding min-width:165px; in the <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns left">